# import data from external workbook that has matching row and column id

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

This is my first time posting here

I have an **error**:

`error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set`

on the line `r2Val = activSheet.Columns(1).Find`...

I have been doing this for a month now and got stuck to the import part

This is the sheet update list
[www.mediafire.com/view/?av8skl7e3ry93p3](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?av8skl7e3ry93p3) 
The above opens a file browser to pick a workbook with the sheet to import

This is the sheet that I want filled
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?r7y2xfa2s7kc9wx

This is where it will get the data from
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?6wp8ywme1kgehqn

My current code for this to work:

```
' updates data based on excel or csv file uploaded
' This version uses "find" to find similar meterID and billing period between 2 worksheets
Sub Push2Sheets(filePath As String, shtName As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If filePath = "False" Then Exit Sub

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook 'workbook to get data from
    Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook 'this workbook to merge

    Set MyWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook 'sets this workbook for merging
    Set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filePath) 'copies source workbook to memory

    Dim activSheet As Worksheet
    Set activSheet = MyWorkbook.Worksheets(shtName) 'selects the worksheet to merge with source sheet
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    If targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 1 Then 'checks first if the target workbook has one or many sheets to draw data
        Set sourceSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Else
        Set sourceSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(shtName)
    End If

    Dim rw As Long 'used as a counter for reading the first column of the source sheet
    Dim Col As Long 'used as a counter for reading the first row of the source sheet
    Dim rVal As String, r2Val As Range 'row value
    Dim cVal As String, c2Val As Range 'cell value

    For rw = 2 To sourceSheet.Rows.Count
    rVal = sourceSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value
    Debug.Print rVal
        'this finds if there is a similar meterID in the target sheet (This Workbook)
        r2Val = activSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=rVal, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not r2Val Is Nothing Then
            For Col = 2 To sourceSheet.Columns.Count
            cVal = sourceSheet.Cells(1, Col).Value
            Debug.Print cVal
                'uses the table headers to find a match and copies the content of source to target sheet if found
                c2Val = activSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=cVal, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not c2Val Is Nothing Then
                sourceSheet.Cells(rw, Col).Copy Destination:=activSheet.Cells(r2Val.Row, c2Val.Column)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Call UniAutoFiller 'adds a new row at the end of the table if there is a new MeterID
            [addrow].Offset(-1, 0).Value = rVal
        End If
    Next

    targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If Not err.Number = 0 Then Call LogInformation(ThisWorkbook.Name & " has error " & err.Number & " " & err.Description & " on " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"))
    MsgBox "Something went wrong :?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Make sure the worksheet name you" & _
     vbNewLine & "are importing match the internal sheet name"
End Sub
```

I'm still a novice when it comes to excel vba

What I want it to do is to:

1. open the external workbook, with the full accomplished worksheet
2. find a match on the meterID with the meterID of the internal sheet,
3. if found find a match on the billing period (date) on the column, if
4. found copy the data where the meterID and billing period got a match
5. repeat 1-4 until it reaches the end of the table

if you want to see the source
get it here: [www.mediafire.com/?9z924s7wtrb5md3](http://www.mediafire.com/?9z924s7wtrb5md3)

this is the sheet I'm trying to import: [www.mediafire.com/view/?i7td9gm336wg6cg](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?i7td9gm336wg6cg)

I cant post images and links yet so if mods or mod class user can clean this up then Im grateful

Any advice, corrections, tips will really help

Comment: Could you tell us what and where it goes wrong and what you have tried to fix it?

Comment: The error message is [br] error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set [br] on the "r2Val = activSheet.Columns(1).Find" part

Comment: Hi @forums, the coding are too long to read, you should try to shortening the question.   in your error message, there's a **TYPO**, it should be `activeSheet` instead of `activSheet`. You may want to use `Option Explicit` as always to avoid this kind of compile error.

Comment: @Larry `Dim activSheet As Worksheet` (sigh...)

Comment: @Neil My bad, jumping to conclusion without taking a look at all the codes..

Comment: the `Set` Keyword is missing

Comment: The Set keyword seemed to fix the initial problem. Kinda dumb of me to forget to use Set. Now just need to optimize the code as it takes Far too long to finish

Comment: My code now just 'hangs' whenever I run it again. Do you think there is something wrong with this <span>sourceSheet.Cells(rw, Col).Copy Destination:=activSheet.Cells(r2Val.Row, c2Val.Column)</span> or any other code that might be locking up excel?

Comment: nevermind got it to work now, thanks for stopping by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance the cause of line 91 error is that you try to set **Range** using just `=`, while `Set` should be used instead, i.e.:

```
Set r2Val = activSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=rVal, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

The same is true for `c2Val` below. Try to correct these first.